# DirectX 11 render BGRA32 Frame

Tags: c#, .net, directx, directx-11, winui-3

First time trying to render something and I have big troubles... I am using [DirectN](https://github.com/smourier/DirectN/tree/master/DirectN) library and [SwapChainSurface](https://github.com/KlearTouch/KlearTouch.MediaPlayer/blob/main/src/KlearTouch.MediaPlayer.WinUI/Controls/SwapChainSurface.cs) class from KlearTouch.MediaPlayer. I am trying to render BGRA32 frame using D3D11Device.

For this I have slightly modified OnNewSurfaceAvailable:

```
public void OnNewSurfaceAvailable2(Action<ID3D11Device, ID3D11DeviceContext> updateSurface)
{
    if (rendering)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        if (this.swapChain is null || swapChainComObject is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        swapChainComObject.GetDesc(out var swapChainDesc).ThrowOnError();

        if (swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width != PanelWidth || swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height != PanelHeight)
        {
            swapChainComObject.ResizeBuffers(2, PanelWidth, PanelHeight, DXGI_FORMAT.DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0).ThrowOnError();
        }

        var device = swapChain.Object.GetDevice1().Object.As<ID3D11Device>();

        device.GetImmediateContext(out var context);

        // context.ClearRenderTargetView(renderTargetView.Object, new []{0f, 1f, 1f, 1f});

        updateSurface(device, context);

        swapChainComObject.Present(1, 0).ThrowOnError();
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        Reinitialize();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\nException: " + ex, nameof(SwapChainSurface) + '.' + nameof(OnNewSurfaceAvailable));
    }

    rendering = false;
}
```

OnSurfaceAvailable2 is called from:

```
void VideoFrameArrived(Bgra32VideoFrame frame)
    {
        DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
        {
            previewSurface.OnNewSurfaceAvailable2((device, context) =>
            {
                var size = frame.m_height * frame.m_height * 4;

                D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC td;
                td.ArraySize = 1;
                td.BindFlags = (uint) D3D11_BIND_FLAG.D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
                td.Usage = D3D11_USAGE.D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
                td.CPUAccessFlags = (uint) D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_FLAG.D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
                td.Format = DXGI_FORMAT.DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
                td.Height = (uint) frame.m_height;
                td.Width = (uint) frame.m_width;
                td.MipLevels = 1;
                td.MiscFlags = 0;
                td.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
                td.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

                D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA srd;
                srd.pSysMem = frame.m_pixelBuffer;
                srd.SysMemPitch = (uint) frame.m_height;
                srd.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

                var texture = device.CreateTexture2D<ID3D11Texture2D>(td, new []{srd});

                var mappedResource = context.Map(texture.Object, 0, D3D11_MAP.D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD);

                var mappedData = mappedResource.pData;
                

                unsafe
                {
                    Buffer.MemoryCopy(frame.m_pixelBuffer.ToPointer(), mappedData.ToPointer(), size, size);
                }

                // Just for debug
                var pixelsInFrame = new byte[size];
                var pixelsInResource = new byte[size];

                Marshal.Copy(frame.m_pixelBuffer, pixelsInFrame, 0, size);
                Marshal.Copy(mappedResource.pData, pixelsInResource, 0, size);
                
                context.Unmap(texture.Object, 0);
            });
        });
    }
```

Problem is that I can't see anything rendered and surface stay black and I assume it should not be.

#### Update: [Project repository](https://github.com/nono3551/BM-Capture)

#### Update 2:

I solved my issue. I had too little knowledge about DX11 so I had to study more how things work there. With this knowledge I updated repository which can display preview from black magic design card. It is just example with many issues so be careful and feel free to look for or inspiration there.

Comment: Do you have a complete reproducing project?

Comment: Rest of code for around DirectX 11 is implemented exactly same as in KlearTouch.MediaPlayer. Application is using BlackMagic capture card and camera. I will put whole project on github and update answer.

Comment: I created public repository with whole project and updated question.

Comment: This project is a whole project that doesn't compile and require 3rd parties. You should post a more simple thing https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What issue does buld produce? I can try to get rid of DeckLinkAPI reference if that is the problem and other unnecessary things.

Comment: That is at least one problem. A minimal example is one that runs kinda everywhere.

Comment: Sorry for not responding. I already solved my issue. I updated question and repository with my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a various amount of issues here.

First on frame arrived, you have

```
var texture = device.CreateTexture2D<ID3D11Texture2D>(td, new []{srd});
```

So your create a texture, but you do not use it anywhere, it needs to be blitted to the swapchain (can do a CopyResource on device context or draw a full screen triangle/quad).

Note that CopyResource will only work if your swapchain has the same size as your incoming texture, which is rather unlikely, so you will have to draw a blit with a shader most likely.

Also you actually copying the data in the texture twice :

```
 var texture = device.CreateTexture2D<ID3D11Texture2D>(td, new []{srd});
```

Since you provide initial data, the content is already there.

also, pitch is incorrect :
srd.SysMemPitch = (uint) frame.m_height;

pitch is the length (in bytes) of a line, so it should be :

```
srd.SysMemPitch = frame.GetRowBytes();
```

Please also note that in case of a non converted Decklink frame,
GetRowBytes can be different from width*4 (they can align row size to multiple of 16/32 or other values).

Next, in the case of resource map, the following is also incorrect :

```
unsafe
{
    Buffer.MemoryCopy(frame.m_pixelBuffer.ToPointer(), mappedData.ToPointer(), size, size);
}
```

You are not checking the pitch/stride requirement of a texture (which can be different as well),

so you need to do :

```
if (mappedResource.RowPitch == frame.GetRowBytes())
{
    //here you can use a direct copy as above
}
else
{
   //here you need to copy data line per line
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer did not help me at all when I fist saw it because I knew too little about directx 11 and rendering. I had to make a big step back and read guides, watch videos and try simple things first. Now it makes much more sense. Especially fist and last part are much more clear and helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Thank to your tips I was able to fix my code. Thanks